# Spring CompositeCacheManager from two modules dep.jar and appl.war?

Tags: java, spring, ehcache, spring-cache

I have the following situation. 
When more than one manager in org.springframework.cache.support.CompositeCacheManager, the cache does not work.

If I have only classManager, is working and application and cache, but the cache works only for classManager.

There is no error, but simply when any query returns an empty object.

There dependencyEE.jar which has defined cache.

```
<cache:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="eManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager"
    p:cache-manager-ref="eCache" />

<bean id="eCache"
    class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"
    p:config-location="classpath:/META-INF/eEhcache.xml"
    p:cacheManagerName="${service.name}.En" p:acceptExisting="false" p:shared="true"/>
```

There application.war which contains dependencyEE.jar and cache CompositeCacheManager. For example from javamelody it is visible, but it does not work. Just getting back to an empty object.

```
<cache:annotation-driven cache-manager="cacheManager"/>
<bean id="classManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager"
    p:cache-manager-ref="classCache" />

<bean id="classCache"
    class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"
    p:config-location="classpath:ehcache.xml" p:cacheManagerName="${service.name}.Class"
    p:acceptExisting="false" />


<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.CompositeCacheManager">
    <property name="cacheManagers">
        <array>
            <ref bean="classManager" />
            <ref bean="eManager" /> 
        </array>
    </property>
    <property name="fallbackToNoOpCache" value="true" />
</bean>
```

How to fix?
These variants http://annotation.spring.codesolution.site/79749-3446-using-spring-cache-annotation-multiple-modules.html - does not work for me.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Hi, why you deleted a line of code? it is necessary in the example.

Comment: "any query returns an empty object.". I didn't get that.  I don't even understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: any news since 2016? Here in the future we keep having the same issue :D

Comment: no, sorry.. I already forgot about this problem.